Starting a PostGIS docker container from the officiel PostGIS docker image without the tiger geocoder
When you start a PostGIS docker container:
$ docker run --name test -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgis/postgis:latest

It also installs the tiger geocoder:
$ docker exec -it test psql -U postgres -c '\dt'
                   List of relations
  Schema  |           Name           | Type  |  Owner   
----------+--------------------------+-------+----------
 public   | spatial_ref_sys          | table | postgres
 tiger    | addr                     | table | postgres
 tiger    | addrfeat                 | table | postgres
 tiger    | bg                       | table | postgres
 tiger    | county                   | table | postgres
 tiger    | county_lookup            | table | postgres
 tiger    | countysub_lookup         | table | postgres
 tiger    | cousub                   | table | postgres
 tiger    | direction_lookup         | table | postgres
 tiger    | edges                    | table | postgres
 tiger    | faces                    | table | postgres
 tiger    | featnames                | table | postgres
 tiger    | geocode_settings         | table | postgres
 tiger    | geocode_settings_default | table | postgres
 tiger    | loader_lookuptables      | table | postgres
 tiger    | loader_platform          | table | postgres
 tiger    | loader_variables         | table | postgres
 tiger    | pagc_gaz                 | table | postgres
 tiger    | pagc_lex                 | table | postgres
 tiger    | pagc_rules               | table | postgres
 tiger    | place                    | table | postgres
 tiger    | place_lookup             | table | postgres
 tiger    | secondary_unit_lookup    | table | postgres
 tiger    | state                    | table | postgres
 tiger    | state_lookup             | table | postgres
 tiger    | street_type_lookup       | table | postgres
 tiger    | tabblock                 | table | postgres
 tiger    | tabblock20               | table | postgres
 tiger    | tract                    | table | postgres
 tiger    | zcta5                    | table | postgres
 tiger    | zip_lookup               | table | postgres
 tiger    | zip_lookup_all           | table | postgres
 tiger    | zip_lookup_base          | table | postgres
 tiger    | zip_state                | table | postgres
 tiger    | zip_state_loc            | table | postgres
 topology | layer                    | table | postgres
 topology | topology                 | table | postgres
(37 rows)

Because I don't need the geocoder, I'm currently mounting an extra SQL script to actually drop it.
So I was wondering if it is possible to start up a PostGIS docker container from its official image without actually installing the tiger geocoder? (both when using docker or a Compose file)

to avoid the unnecessary tables, you can create a custom Docker image  that drops the tiger schema using a SQL script, and then use a docker-compose.yml file to mount a SQL script that drops the tiger schema after the container starts.
so basically you need to run a script to drop the schema after startup.
you can use an SQL script like:


DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS tiger CASCADE;
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS topology CASCADE;



